# How to remove a regex added to a textfield?

Tags: ios, objective-c, regex, uitextfield

I have a specific situation in which at first I have to add a regex to my textfield and then after a while I have to remove it. I added it successfully but I dont know how to remove it. If someone can tell me how update the regex on textfield then that can also work. I have tried overriding the older regex but its not working at all. Here is the code I am having trouble with, sometimes the if condition is true and at times the control goes to the else block.

```
-(void)addRegexInformation{

if ([[USERDEFAULT stringForKey:USERSELECTEDLANGUAGE] isEqualToString:@"Persian"] || [[USERDEFAULT stringForKey:USERSELECTEDLANGUAGE] isEqualToString:@"Spanish"] || [[USERDEFAULT stringForKey:USERSELECTEDLANGUAGE] isEqualToString:@"German"]) {

    [emailTxtFld addRegx:REGEX_EMAIL withMsg:[UtilityHandler convertIntoSelectedLanguage:CustomLocalisedString(@"validEmail")]];

    [passwordTxtFld addRegx:REGEX_USER_NAME_LIMIT withMsg:[UtilityHandler convertIntoSelectedLanguage:CustomLocalisedString(@"enterPassMsg")]];
}
else{
    [emailTxtFld addRegx:REGEX_EMAIL withMsg:CustomLocalisedString(@"validEmail")];

    [passwordTxtFld addRegx:REGEX_USER_NAME_LIMIT withMsg:CustomLocalisedString(@"enterPassMsg")];

}
```

}

Comment: you don't add regex you just evaluate text of textfield there is no adding or removing it

Comment: @RahulGUsai so what do I do if I want to evaluate the same text on two different criteriae at two different time?

Comment: Its always better to paste the piece of code, so that others can help you. https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: @AmanChhabra I have edited the question, please let me know if this gives you any hint what might be going wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`addRegx` is not built into the iOS SDK but instead is an API added by a couple different open source Text Field validators, like the one found at https://github.com/dhawaldawar/TextFieldValidator ([documentation found here](http://www.thinkotech.com/ios/uitextfield-validation-for-ios/)).

There's also a more recent (as of two years ago) version found at https://github.com/canicelebrate/AETextFieldValidator and this can be incorporated via Cocoapods.

You're not specifying which one you're using so we'll just assume `AETextFieldValidator` for now.

***GhazalahTextFieldValidator.h***

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "AETextFieldValidator.h"

@interface GhazalahTextFieldValidator : AETextFieldValidator

@end
```

***GhazalahTextFieldValidator.m***

```
#import "GhazalahTextFieldValidator.h"

@interface GhazalahTextFieldValidator() {
    NSMutableArray *arrRegx;
}
@end

@implementation GhazalahTextFieldValidator

- (void)emptyRegxArray {
    [arrRegx removeAllObjects];
}

@end
```

Set your textfields to be these validators and you should be good to go.